# Referring to the text of a text

Tags: word-choice

Here are a few attributes that a text may have: "name", "length", "quality", etc.

What's the name of the text attribute that refers to the text itself? Would that be the text's "content", the text's "body" or something else?

Comment: The only word for the text attribute that refers to the text itself is 'self-referential'.  Need more context.

Comment: I'm not looking for just a word, but rather, an attribute - a belonging of the subject - the text. A text can not possess a "self-referential".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *body* certainly works. *The text itself* also works. As far as I know, there is no one, single clear-cut "right" answer to this.

Comment: Yes - "body of the text" is standard.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a variable or a field that contains text, the "text itself" is normally considered to be the *value* of the variable or the *content* of the field.

If by "text" you mean "a written work" such as a book or short story, then *body* or *content* are good ways to refer to the actual story itself (as opposed to features that describe it such as its length, author, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Text is text. It doesn't require another noun to write it down.

That said, you can refer to the "characters" or "words" or "wording" of a text. You can refer to its contents as well, but if you refer to the singular "content" you are probably more likely to be talking about a passage's meaning or subject matter.